# FormMapper key press issue In sonata admin using symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am new in sonata admin, I add field in form mapper and that show in add and edit page but for emailid field , I not able to press @ and . (dot) key.it only accept character and digit. Below is Code that I use.

```
                   $formMapper
                   ->add('username',TextType::class,['required'=>true,'disabled' => false,'label' => 'User Name'])
                   ->add('email',EmailType::class,['required'=>true,'disabled' => false,'empty_data' => '','label' => 'Email']);
```

what missing for email id field?

Comment: I guess, this is User entity, but can you provide the code of your entity?